# Sending data to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have searched my problem before posting this question, but failed to find a solution. 
I need to send a json string to php file but unable to do so, can some one please help with my problems below: I'm new to php and jquery and is struggling, Need your cooperation please.

I have a function that captures data on the text file:

```
function updateVal() {
var node_list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var c = 0;
var fieldName = [];
var fieldText = []
var ID = [];
for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) {
    var node = node_list[i];
    if (node.getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
        fieldName[c] = node.name;
        fieldText[c] = node.value;
        ID[c] = node.id;
        c++;
    }
}
var postData = {
    fieldName: fieldName,
    fieldText: fieldText,
    ID: ID
};
 var dataString = JSON.stringify(postData);


console.log(JSON.stringify(postData));
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {myData:postData}
        })

//return JSON.stringify(postData);
}
```

My update.php is like this:

```
<?php
$json = $_POST['json'];
$result = json_decode($json);

echo $result;
echo $_POST['myData']);?>
```

On loading this: I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Moreover, I'm not sure if the data being sent to php or not.
Can experts pls validate.

Comment: Try `data: JSON.stringify(postData),`

Comment: @Tushar Not working. Internal Server error only, saying unable to decode value

Comment: Try `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', data: {json: JSON.stringify(postData),`

Comment: I think this worked, but how do I see if the string is being transferred to php or not. I tried doing echo, but nothing is being displayed.

Comment: why not just `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to see what you are getting ?  also try what @Tushar is telling

Comment: a basic question: where would var_dump($_REQUEST) will display the output? no output is generated on page. so slightly confused

Answer (score 3):

The 500 (internal server error) means something went wrong on the server's side. So check the apache error log for more details

you may find apache log here `/var/log/apache2/`

Answer (score 2):

On client side (javascript code):

```
data: JSON.stringify(postData)
```

On server side (PHP code):

```
json_decode($_POST["data"])
```

Answer (score 1):

u commented the closing braces of the function with the return statement.
change this :

```
//return JSON.stringify(postData);}
```

to:

```
//return JSON.stringify(postData);
}
```

Also :

```
data: JSON.stringify(postData),
```

IN update.php

```
$json = $_POST['myData'];
$result = json_decode($myData);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, updated my question to reflect the change

Comment: i have no idea what that has to do with internal server error

Comment: ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL); u can try putting these to check for any errors. or check for apache error log

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I'm able to overcome the internal server error, however how do I make sure that the json object is being passed correctly ? can you pls help

Answer (score 0):

Comment from @Tushar helped me resolving the issue

```
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', data: {json: JSON.stringify(postData)
```

Answer (score 0):

sent Ajax request to php Page to Get data

```
$.ajax({ method: "POST", // it may be Get url: "some.php", //page where you sent request data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" } //attibutes you want to take on that page }) .done(function( msg ) { // sucessfull reponse alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); });
```